# Can a deleted question be accessed indefinitely with its URL?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

If I delete one of my questions, can I access it indefinitely with its URL, or can only access it for 60 days after deletion?

This [SE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/327224) seems to indicate the answer is "**can access indefinitely with URL**", but it does not say so explicitly.

Hence my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access it indefinitely if you have the URL, and are one of the following:

- The poster of the question
- A 10k+ rep user for the site
- Author of an answer to the question (with less than 10k rep you'll see only the deleted question and your own answer, not other answers)
- A moderator for the site