# As a low rep user on meta or chat, how can I follow a link to a question after deletion?

Tags: discussion, chat, meta, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

I think everyone knows this problem. There is a discussion on meta with references to example questions. Let's say, the purpose of the discussion is to establish, if those referenced questions are off topic and should be closed. As a side note, this could apply to answers as well.

Then an agreement is reached and some of these referenced questions get indeed closed and later deleted.

Now a new user is reading up on the discussion and would like to see those example questions. This is usually critical to get an understanding of the discussion. All s/he gets is a 404.

This is highly undesirable as the original reference of the discussion is lost. Some positions are not fully understandable any more.

[While certain users appear to be able to see these questions,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298461/can-a-deleted-question-be-accessed-indefinitely-with-its-url) the low rep user, who is trying to get a better understanding of the site, is not.

Can a low rep user flag such a discussion for moderator invention? Could, should and would a moderator make these links accessible to everyone again?

What is the recommended thing to do here?

Comment: On big issue mod on SF usually give a printscreen of it, to help the discussion. I dont know if the practice is the same everywhere

Comment: @yagmoth so I understand it would be a good idea to re-ask this question on the specific site again? My question came up while reading on Lifehacks_meta.SE, I assumed there was a SE wide policy in place.

Comment: Yes, I would ask in comment on the question you wanted more information, usually someone will edit to add the printscreen (unless it's insult or inappropriate content.)

Comment: you could ask for a screenshot to a high rep user

Comment: [Screenshots should in almost all cases be provided](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326223/is-it-okay-to-show-a-screenshot-of-a-deleted-question-to-low-reputation-users/326226#326226) for a Meta question about a problematic post. Otherwise, yes, participation is limited when it shouldn't be. E.g., [Meta.Skeptics question that is useless for low-rep users](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3962/do-we-need-an-update-on-what-constitutes-original-research#comment12365_3962) because they can't see the subject material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't.

This is one reason posts being self-contained is essential.

In theory, if you know it's going to get deleted, you might find it cached somewhere (like Internet archive). After the fact, *sometimes* a screenshot might help.

On chat, the onebox doesn't go away IIRC, but that's all you get.

In most cases though, a deleted post is something we want *gone* for whatever reason so any screenshots or other way of getting access to it is on a case-by-case basis. There's a few cases where a 10ker or moderator helped - possibly on meta, but you are totally going to make a compelling case for it. On the whole though, deleted questions being deleted and gone is a *feature*, not a bug.